# JLabel - how to hide a text?

Tags: java, swing, hide, jlabel

I have JLabel with an icon and text. Is there any possibility to **hide** only JLabel's **text**? I don't want to hide whole component (setVisible(false)), but only text, so an icon remains visible. I'd like to still use getText and setText methods.

Thanks for Your help!

Comment: "I'd like to still use getText and setText methods."  Use them for *what,* if not displaying text?  This design has an odd odor to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, there's no direct way to do this. But you could try some of the following:

1. Extend JLabel and override the setText() and getText() methods. These should store the text you give it in a new String field. Every time you call setText it should only delegate to super.setText() is your label-text is not invisible. Then you could add a method that switches visibility. If you call setTextVisibility() with true, the class should call super.setText() with a string of spaces.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
  public class MyLabel extends JLabel {
    private String labelText;
    private boolean labelTextVisible = true;

    private MyLabel( String text, Icon icon, int horizontalAlignment ) {
      super( text, icon, horizontalAlignment );
      labelText = text;
    }

    private MyLabel( String text, int horizontalAlignment ) {
      super( text, horizontalAlignment );
      labelText = text;
    }

    private MyLabel( String text ) {
      super( text );
      labelText = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void setText( String text ) {
      if ( labelTextVisible ) {
        super.setText( text );
      }
      labelText = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
      return labelText;
    }

    public void setLabelTextVisible( boolean labelVisible ){
      if(labelVisible){
        if(!labelText.equals( super.getText() )){
          super.setText( labelText );
        }
      }else{
        int spaceCount = super.getText().length();
        String hiddenText = "";
        for ( int i = 0; i < spaceCount; i++ ) {
          hiddenText+=" ";
        }
        super.setText(hiddenText);
      }
      this.labelTextVisible = labelVisible;
    }

    public boolean getLabelTextVisible(){
      return labelTextVisible;
    }
  }
```

1. (This is more of a hack, but it could work) Make the foregroundcolor of the label match the background color so the text is no longer visible.

Answer (score 4):

Is this too obvious?

`label.setText("");`

If you really just want to hide it, you could set the foreground color to be the same as the background.  Maybe that would suffice (and might be necessary to prevent the icon from moving, depending how you have the alignment set).

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same problem and my workaround was to simply use the `setName()` and `getName()` methods in place of the `setText()` and `getText()` methods. Hope it will help. The problem with `setToolTipText()` is that the tool tip is displayed on mouse hover.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem today.

My JLabel has an icon and I needed only the icon to be displayed. I had a MouseListener and for that I required the text of the label to uniquely identify the label.

My workaround was to use `setToolTipText()` instead of `setText()` and use `getToolTipText()` instead of  `getText()` in the MouseListener.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to just set the font to 0!!
Try it out. works fine.

```
label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Grande", 1, 0));
```